# Prevent showing details when hyperlink is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, hyperlink

I'm wondering how to prevent showing details row in DataGrid, when somebody clicks on hyperlink or button inside a cell. It's really annoying when you try to click hyperlink and details show instead of link.

Another problem is that I have some action buttons in one column, so when details are collapsed then you must first click row to show details and then click for example edit button.

Sample:

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Column0 { get; set; }
        public string Mail { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
        {
            get
            {
                ObservableCollection<Item> i = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
                i.Add(new Item() { Column0 = "dsaads", Mail = "mail@sad.com" });
                i.Add(new Item() { Column0 = "wdads", Mail = "adsdas@sad.com" });
                return i;
            }
        }

        public void HyperlinkClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column0" Binding="{Binding Column0}" />
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Mail" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Mail}" >
                    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,2,0" />
                            <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="HyperlinkClick" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="100">

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

To see the problem: select first row and then try to click on hyperlink in a second row.

Comment: If you want better help, faster; always supply code :)

Comment: There's no need to add neither "How to" or "datagrid" to the question title, since the "how to" is redundant due to implication and "datagrid" is redundant since it's already among the tags.

Comment: Friend, there is a very small chance you're going to get an answer for this question. Provide some code and some things you've tried.

Comment: Ok, I'll prepare some code :-), but I think the question is simple for someone who has already worked with DataGrid and details row :-).

Comment: I've added some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the tunneling event on hyperlink "**OnPreviewMouseDown**", that will prevent the event reaching the DataGrid which shows the RowDetailsTemplate.

```
 private void OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var hyperlink = (Hyperlink)sender;
        Process.Start(hyperlink.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri);
        e.Handled = true;
        }
```

**Full Example:**

```
<Window x:Class="DummyTree.DataGridTest" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="DataGridTest" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="First Name">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <Hyperlink PreviewMouseDown="OnPreviewMouseDown" NavigateUri="http://www.google.com">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                </Hyperlink>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" details here" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace DummyTree
{
    public partial class DataGridTest : Window
    {
        public DataGridTest()
        {
            DataContext = new CustomerVM();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var hyperlink = (Hyperlink)sender;
        Process.Start(hyperlink.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri);
        e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    public class CustomerVM
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public CustomerVM()
        {
            Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer> { new Customer { Name = "Leo" }, new Customer { Name = "Om" } };
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at updated event handler in code sample above ^